# Particle system deforms in the render

Tags: particles, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to render grass made out of a hair particle system and it deforms itself every time I render it on EEVEE, even though it looks right in the viewport.

I changed the shader so it's not that, and I've noticed it happens when the particles count goes over 5250 (I'm trying to render at 15000). Below I share the images. I'd share the .blend file but blendswap isn't uploading it and I believe that's how we're supposed to share it?
Following is the link to the .blend file https://pasteall.org/blend/b42803bc22bb4ebfb7e683e56a1f5dc6

Ok (viewport):
[image]

Render:
[image]

Comment: Hello :). You can use https://pasteall.org/blend/ for uploading your .blend files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, the children particles were too many for rendering.